# Javascript printing to html with percent sign

Tags: javascript

I get a bunch of JSON data through an XHR request, and get the following data back:

```
{"data_list" : [[1, "Title1", "0.54%"], [2, "Title2", "2.98%"]]}
```

Then I try to loop through that data, and put it in the console with console.log:

```
var len = json.data_list.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   console.log(json.data_list[i]);
}
```

But I don't get the same percentages:

```
[1, "Title1", "0.24%"]
[2, "Title2", "0.00%"]
```

Anyone know why I would get the right data for the first two fields, but not the same percentages? Even if I take out the percent signs in the JSON response, I still get the wrong numbers.

Assume that the variable is valid, I'm using a library that maps the json variable to json.data_list.

**I AM NOT SO BRIGHT**

Somewhere the XHR request got mangled by Dojo. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What library are you using?  Since it is a string, there is no reason for this value to change.  Try iterating through the returned data outside of this library.

Comment: Dojo, to get the xhr data. So it maps the result to a variable json, so working on json.data_list works on that part of the json. I'll try something else.

Comment: It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/8nTUM/ so your issue must be somewhere else (maybe in the conversion from JSON to object?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"data-list" is an invalid identifier as you expect it to act, so it's interpreted as subtraction. Try using bracket notation:

```
json["data-list"].length
```

and

```
json["data-list"][i]
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7bgvV/

Comment: Sorry, just edited OP. Assume that is a valid variable. I'm using a library that maps it to json.data_list.

Comment: @cwill747 You didn't edit the second problem - `json.data-list[i]`

Comment: I'll edit it in the OP, this isn't copy and pasted code. For the sake of argument pretend it works.

Comment: @cwill747 Well there's **no** reason why this would happen, unless your "mapping" messed it up. Like my demo, it should work just fine, so either post actual code and an example showing it not working, or debug some more

Comment: console.log(json['data_list'][j]); still gives me [1, "Title1", "0.24%"]

Comment: @cwill747 Are you 100% sure that the values returned from the XHR are what you expect? Like I've already shown in my example, the problem is elsewhere, and that's what you need to post/debug

Comment: Hmm fairly sure. If I just do an HTTP request with the same URL that I  get using Dojo, I get the response that I expect.

Comment: WOW YOU WERE RIGHT. Inspecting developer tools, somewhere in the response something gets mangled. Well I'm an idiot.

Comment: @cwill747 That's my point. If your XHR retrieves the *correct* values, **then** you do something with them, there's the problem. At this point in your code (what you've posted and what I've shown works fine), something else must've modified it to make it "not work".

Comment: @cwill747 Haha glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

`var len = json.data-list.length;` looks like a subtraction operation to the JavaScript VM. You need to use this method: `json['data-list'].length.`

If you have no control over the method returning this data, try something like this:

```
var ajaxStr = '{"data-list" : [[1, "Title1", "0.54%"], [2, "Title2", "2.98%"]]}]';
ajaxStr = ajaxStr.replace(/\"([\w]+)-([\w]+)\"/g, "\"$1$2\"");
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited OP. Assume that is a valid variable. I'm using a library that maps it to json.data_list.